# How to Submit Permission(read_stream, publish_actions) for Review on Facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-permissions, publish-actions, cfreadstream

I want to get a user's wall post (photo or video) shared from Facebook pages. I am using `graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed` option to get this data via `read_stream` permission. Is there any other option available for the required task?

I have to post status on user's wall through my app whenever required. I am using `publish_actions` option.

The problem is that these permissions need review from Facebook.
I'm working on the website and App review required Privacy Policy URL. Is this possible to submit for review based on local host site address? 
What should I write in Privacy Policy URL and Terms of Service URL options??? Because my website is in development phase and I need user's account data for further work.

Answer (score 2):

About `read_stream`:

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client
>   on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example,
>   Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In
>   addition, Web, Desktop, in-car and TV apps will not be granted this
>   permission.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-read_stream

You may try to use `/me/statuses` with the `user_status` permission instead.

Obviously, you cannot send anything in that only runs on localhost, you should have a working prototype showing how exactly you are using the permissions. Also, you are not allowed to autopost anything to the user wall just because he authorized `publish_actions`. Every single entry has to get approved by the user and every single entry must be 100% user generated.

Comment: " every single entry must be 100% user generated" does that mean the apps like postplanner.com are illigal - because it lets u post the trending content, which is not generated by user, also the content is reposted without original authors permission.

Comment: if they prefill the message, then yes. the facebook terms are pretty clear about that.

Comment: on pages, it´s normally allowed. definitely not on user profiles. but you should not do autoposting in any case.

Comment: That app allows both on pages and user profiles though

Comment: in that case it is not allowed and should actually be reported to facebook